# What are interesting uses of the factor theorem on groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Ash's "Basic Abstract Algebra". Here:

> [image]

I understood the theorem but I lack "interesting" examples to use it. I have tried some examples in modular arithmetic but nothing seemed to yield something nice.

It could also be the case that this theorem (called "factor theorem" is just a stepping stone for further theorems (he presents the isomorphism theorems after that). So, does this theorem has some use for something else?

Comment: Certainly this is a basic stepping stone in group theory.  It isn't clear from the picture you posted, but the requirement to find $\overline f$ that makes the diagram commute is for normal subgroup  $N$ to be contained in the kernel of $f$.  The commutative diagram summarizes what we call a "universal mapping property" of the group quotient construction $G/N$.  Searching for "exact sequences" will yield a thick seam of applications in group theory as viewed through category theory.

Comment: You will find similar theorems in most mathematical fields. This theorem is an very, very important tool in applying group theory. You need a group with certain properties. Usually the easiest way to construct it is to start with some large group (most commonly the free group on some set of generators), then mod out everything you don't want. But now you need to build homomorphisms to apply it to your purpose. Generally, you have to also build those on the larger group as well, but obeying the characteristics you are interested in, then use the factor theorem to get the map you actually want.